# Finding a specific Window using its title hashed value

Tags: python, encryption, hash, reverse-engineering, malware

I've been decompiling a piece of code I believe is malware and I'm trying to figure out what it does. It searches for a specific window title and uses the name of that window to decode the rest of its instructions. I've tried just running lists of common windows titles (Notepad, Document1 - Microsoft Word, etc) through it to come up with the right window title.

I've rewritten the hash it uses in Python:

```
def encode( inStr ):
  a = 0x133F00D
  i = 0

  for j in inStr:
    temp = ord(j)*8 * ((i << 0xC)+1)
    a = a^ temp
    i = i + 1
  print hex(a)
```

and I'm looking for a string that gives me the value 0x2227205. Looking at the hash function, it looks like it's one way and has collisions. What's a good approach to finding what window title it's trying to grab? Is there a list on a malwire prevention site of common window titles? Should I run a dictionary attack? What's the best approach?

Comment: If the malware author has gone to that amount of effort to obfuscate the code, I suspect you won't find the window title in a dictionary of common titles - there will be some unicode substitutions in there somewhere to make the title visibly plausible but hard to guess.  Unless someone has encountered and published this malware before, you may be stuck with a brute-force search.

Answer (score 0):

If the window title is long enough you won't find it with a brute force attack and probably it would not even help you to find a title which matches the hash. The malware could just check if there is another instance of itself.

I would suggest running the malware in a vm or even better dedicated computer (probably without network to be sure, or a fake network to check activity) with a debugger. You can then check if you can find windows matching the hash in there.

If you stick to that python code btw make sure you have the same overflow behavior as in the malware (same length of integers especially).